# How to fix 404 errors when serving static files through nginx

Tags: nginx

I have to applications running using flask and nginx as a reverse proxy.  I am having issues serving the static files from my `/birthday/` location.

```
location /{
    proxy_pass http:127.0.0.1:6060;
}
```

The app that is having issues is.

```
 location /birthday/
 {
     proxy_pass http:127.0.0.1:6061;
 }
```

I have tired the following.

```
 location /birthday/{
   root /var/www/birthday_app/static;
   try_files $uri @bday
 }
 location @bday{
    proxy_pass http:127.0.0.1:6061;
  }
```

When I serve up `http://127.0.0.1/birthday/static/image.png` I get status no found.  How do I fix the birthday app to serve static files.

Comment: Thanks I added that `location ~* /birthday/ {}`.  But how do I serve the static files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the URI `/birthday/static/image.png` points to a file at `/var/www/birthday_app/static/image.png`? You cannot use `root` on it's own in this situation. You will need to use `rewrite...break` or `alias`.

Also, if the URIs beginning with `/birthday/static/` serve static files and all other URIs beginning with `/birthday/` reverse proxy upstream, you can divide your configuration into two `location` blocks.

For example:

```
location /birthday/static/ {
    alias /var/www/birthday_app/static/;
}
location /birthday/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6061;
}
```

The value of the `location` and `alias` should both end with `/` or neither end with `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

The URI `/birthday/foo` will be passed upstream to `http://127.0.0.1:6061/birthday/foo` without modification. If you need the URI mapped to `http://127.0.0.1:6061/foo` instead, add a trailing `/` to the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: I am now really confused.  I can access `http://127.0.0.1/birthday/static/balloon.jpg` That can be accessed from any sub folder in static.  `http://127.0.0.1/birthday/static/image/balloon.jpg` works however 'http://127.0.0.1/birthday/static/image/balloon.css' does not work.

Comment: You have a file called `balloon.css` in the directory at `/var/www/birthday_app/static/image/`?

Comment: OK I think it is working. I believe it was a cached response.  After restarting the browser it started working.  Thanks for all of the help.